# swift on macOS: AVAudioPlayer stops immediately

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, avaudioplayer, macos-sierra

I have a macOS (not iOS) project in Swift.

In my main AppDelegate.swift I instantiate a class called PlaySound then call startSound()

The class called PlaySound.swift plays an mp3. However, I hear no sound unless I put a sleep() soon after I call play in either class file. I thought I was losing reference to the class instantiation, but I am able to call a test print function as you see and that works.

Does anyone know why the audio is stopping?

thanks for any help
-Bill

```
import Cocoa 

@NSApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
        let myCheck = PlaySound()
        myCheck.startSound()
        sleep(7)
        myCheck.testPrint()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

PlaySound class below...

```
import Foundation
import AVKit

class PlaySound {

    var soundFile = "crickets"
    var myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    func startSound() {
        do {
            self.myPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundFile, ofType: "mp3")!))
            //set the number of loops to "infinite"
            self.myPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
            self.myPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            //set the volume to muted
            self.myPlayer.volume = 0
            //play the sound
            self.myPlayer.play()
            //fade in the sound
            self.myPlayer.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: 2)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    } // end of startSound

    func fadeOutSound() {
        myPlayer.setVolume(0, fadeDuration: 10)
        myPlayer.stop()
    }

    func testPrint() {
        print("yes this works")
    }
} // end of aclass
```

Comment: Before using sleep(), find out what it does.

Comment: @ElTomato thanks for writing back. Did you mean I should look into what sleep() does? Or, that I should find out what the code is doing immediately before sleep() is called?

Comment: did you solve this?  I have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Once `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is finished `myCheck` goes out of scope and is deinited, so there's nothing left to play the sound. You could keep it in memory like this:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    let myCheck = PlaySound()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        myCheck.startSound()
    }
}
```